# i dont know what is wrong with my code. When i run the code it is just in a loop and wont stop the loop

Tags: python

[Here is the assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vmil.png)

and here is the code

```
shoppinglist = []
user = shoppinglist.append(input("Enter your items "))

while user != 'end':
    user = shoppinglist.append(input())
    
shoppinglist.sort()

no_items = len(shoppinglist)
print(no_items)
```

the loop condition was while user != 'end' but even if i input end the loop doesn't stop.

Comment: `shoppinglist.append(...)` always returns `None`. `None` will never be equal to `'end'`.

Answer (score 1):

`shoppinglist.append()` returns `None`, not the item that was appended.

Since `append` puts the item on the end, you can see what got appended by taking the `[-1]` list element:

```
shoppinglist = []
shoppinglist.append(input("Enter your items "))
while shoppinglist[-1] != 'end':
    shoppinglist.append(input())
shoppinglist.pop()  # remove the last element, which is "end"
```